# HTML5 Canvas Checkered Pattern

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a retro pixelated background painting. The x and y position of "pixels" are odd and even accordingly. This seems to work for a resolution (res variable) of 4 and then the % operator does not seem to work.

```
function drawPixelatedBackground()
{
    var res = 5;

    for (var x=0; x<settings.width/res;x++ )
    { 
        for (var y=0;y<settings.height/res;y++)
        {
            if ( (x%2==0) && (y%2==0) )
            {
                nx = x * (settings.width/res);
                ny = y * (settings.width/res);
                ctx.fillStyle= settings.colors.Fill;
                ctx.fillRect(nx,ny, nx+  (settings.width/res),ny+   (settings.height/res) );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go. The pattern you can see here is nice I agree. But all I want is a matrix chessboard style.
http://jsfiddle.net/zwuLcntj/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Little issue with your logic. I'll explain mine below.

http://jsfiddle.net/2eee9moq/2/

```js
function drawCheckeredBackground(can, nRow, nCol) {
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var w = can.width;
    var h = can.height;

    nRow = nRow || 8;    // default number of rows
    nCol = nCol || 8;    // default number of columns

    w /= nCol;            // width of a block
    h /= nRow;            // height of a block

    for (var i = 0; i < nRow; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0, col = nCol / 2; j < col; ++j) {
            ctx.rect(2 * j * w + (i % 2 ? 0 : w), i * h, w, h);
        }
    }

    ctx.fill();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

drawCheckeredBackground(canvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

- The nested `for` loop draws the blocks in one row.

  - `2 * j * w + (i % 2 ? 0 : w)` is shifting the x co-ordinate of each block every other row.

Comment: Pretty nice, smooth and clever. Thanks. Thumbs up. I'll keep the other function to create persian Teppiche :)

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the rows and columns like so:

```
for (let column = 0; column < board.columns; column++) {
  for (let row = 0; row < board.rows; row++) {

  }
}
```

and create the checkered pattern by drawing a rectangle if either of the following conditions is true:

- **row is even and the column is odd**
- **row is odd and the column is even**

In code:

```
if (row % 2 === 0 && column % 2 === 1 || row % 2 === 1 && column % 2 === 0) {
  canvas.context.rect(
    column * column_width,
    row * row_height,
    column_width,
    row_height
  );
}
```

```js
const canvas = {
  element: document.querySelector("canvas"),
  context: document.querySelector("canvas").getContext('2d')
}

const board = {
  rows: 15,
  columns: 17,
  colors: {
    light: '#a3cf53',
    dark: '#abd55a'
  }
}

canvas.context.beginPath();
canvas.context.fillStyle = board.colors.dark;
canvas.context.rect(0, 0, canvas.element.width, canvas.element.height);
canvas.context.fill();

canvas.context.beginPath();
canvas.context.fillStyle = board.colors.light;
for (let column = 0; column < board.columns; column++) {
  for (let row = 0; row < board.rows; row++) {
    if (row % 2 === 0 && column % 2 === 1 || row % 2 === 1 && column % 2 === 0) {
      canvas.context.rect(
        column * canvas.element.width / board.columns,
        row * canvas.element.height / board.rows,
        canvas.element.width / board.columns,
        canvas.element.height / board.rows
      );
    }
  }
}
canvas.context.fill();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="595" height="525"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

To alternate color the squares we can use the fact that the diagonal squares at say (1,1), (2,2), (3,3),... will be of the same color say white and (1,2), (2,3), (3,4),... will be of the same color say black. We notice a pattern here that in `(col, row)` if `col` and `row` both are even or both are odd then squares have the same color(white) otherwise they have other color(black).

code logic:

```
if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0)){
    square is white/color1
}
else{
    square is black/color2
}
```

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board")
const ctx = board.getContext("2d")

let cols = 8 
let rows = 8
let squareSize = 50

function drawCheckeredBoard(ctx, squareSize, rows, cols) {
    let whiteSquareColor = "#ffe6cc"
    let blackSquareColor = "#cc6600"

    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0)) 
                ctx.fillStyle = whiteSquareColor
            else ctx.fillStyle = blackSquareColor
            ctx.fillRect(i * squareSize, j * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize)
        }
}

drawCheckeredBoard(ctx, squareSize, rows, cols)
```

```html
<canvas id="board" width="400" height="400">
```